# how to override tableview row rightImage in titanium appcelerator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, appcelerator-mobile

I want to add an button in right side of tableview row, I have seen rightImage property in UI.TableViewRow. Is it possible to override the image view or can we add button under rightImage

rowObject.rightImage.add(mybutton);

Answer (score 1):

In your TableViewRow, create a globalView with horizontal layout

```
var globalView = Ti.UI.createView({
   width: "100%",
   layout: "horizontal",
   ...
});
```

Then create 2 other views, the leftView (width equals to 80% for example) and the rightView which contains a button (set the width to 20%), then add the leftView and the rightView to your globalView.

```
globalView .add(leftView);
globalView.add(rightView);
```

Make sure that you set correctly the height for your components.